# Fancytree load data from specific json element

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-4, fancytree

I am using `Laravel 4` and `fancytree`.

I have an `api` call that return `JSON` data something like this :

```
{
    "error":false,
    "survey_data":"[{
        "id": 1,
        "type": "group",
        "subtype": null,
        "title": "General ",
        "parent": null,
        "children": [{
            "id": 30,
            "type": "question",
            "subtype": "boolean",
            "title": "Did you..?",
            "parent": 1,
            "children": [{
                "id": 31,
                "type": "answer",
                "subtype": null,
                "title": "Yes",
                "parent": 30,
                "children": []
            }]
        }]
    }]
}
```

I want to load the `JSON` of element `survey_data` into `fancytree`.

Currently, my code is something like this :

```
var tree = function (treeDiv,sourceURL){
     treeDiv.fancytree({
         source : sourceURL
     })
}
```

In variable `sourceURL` I am passing the `api url` and I have verified with firebug that I am getting the correct `JSON` data. But however I am not sure how to load this `survey_data` `JSON` as a source.

I have also tried :

```
source: jQuery.ajax({
            url: sourceURL,
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            complete: function(xhr, textStatus) {
            },
            success: function(data, textStatus, xhr) {
                return data.survey_data;
            },
            error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            }
        })
```

But getting error :

```
Uncaught Error: Assertion failed: source must contain (or be) an array of children
```

Please note that I am using the latest version of `fancytree`.

Can anybody help me?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved it myself :

```
treeDiv.fancytree({
    source: {
      url: sourceURL,
    },

    postProcess: function(event, data) {
      data.result = $.parseJSON(data.response.survey_data);
    }
}]
```

Comment: Any idea how I would do this for the lazy loading? When lazy loading, the postProcess function is not being called.